# Passing/sorting comma separated list as custom dimension in Google Analytics

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I'm passing a comma separated list of Wordpress tags for a page(post) as a custom dimension to Google Analytics.  It's returned in the report, predictably as a list of tag groups:

```
1. tag1, tag2, tag4 | 4 pageviews
2. tag2, tag3, tag5 | 3 pageviews 
3. tag2, tag5, tag6 | 3 pageviews
4. tag1, tag5, tag6 | 2 pageviews
```

Is there a way though a filter or regEx to manipulate that view/report so it's sorted and grouped naturally:

```
1. tag1 | 20 pageviews
2. tag3 | 15 pageviews
3. tag2 | 12 pageviews
```

Comment: Probably what have you tried?

Comment: I tried a few random RegEx filters to no avail.  I'm not that versed in the advanced capabilities of GA and surprisingly most of my Google searches came up empty on this topic so I wanted to ensure it was even possible before investigating further.  I didn't think this would be that uncommon a use case.